# How do I make my side navigation bar scrollable along Y-axis if it exceeds the viewport height?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am basically creating a sidebar, that pushes up the `main` element as I click on the button that says `open`.

Consider the set of code, I have:
My CSS Styles:

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 496px;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

And then my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Apple</a>
  <a href="#">Google</a>
  <a href="#">Hyundai</a>
  <a href="#">Toyota</a>
  <a href="#">Mitsubishi</a>
  <a href="#">Corolla</a>
  <a href="#">Audi</a>
  <a href="#">McLaren</a>
  <a href="#">Grace</a>
  <a href="#">Raus</a>
  <a href="#">Electra</a>
  <a href='#' id='showlamborghini'>Lamborghini</a>
  <div id='showid' style='display:none'>
         <a href="#">About</a>
         <a href="#">Services</a>
         <a href="#">Clients</a>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>  
         <a href="#">Company Owners</a>
         <a href="#">Shares</a>
         <a href="#">Market Value</a>
         <a href="#">Economical Issues</a>  
         <a href="#">Adress</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Tesla</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Finally, I have my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('showlamborghini').onclick=start;
function start() {
var z=document.getElementById('showid').style;
z.display=(z.display=='block'?'none':'block');
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Now, my problem is that, when my viewport height is about 496px, which is much less than the total height of the `sidenav` id I have prepared, only the portion that can be shown in the given space are displayed. I added `overflow-y:'auto'` style in my CSS but that didn't work. It was supposed to show me the `Lamborghini` link that I was supposed to click on to see the links it further has in it. But, `Lamborghini` is not properly shown. Even the link `Tesla` is not shown (not a bit) at all.

Moreover, what's even more confusing is that, if I shift my `showlamborghini` from Lamborghini to Electra as a new id like `showelectra`, then also it does not show me the `Tesla` id. But `overflow-y:auto`, as you can see, only works when I click on any of the ids like `showelectra` or `showlamborghini` to show up the sub-links under `showid` id.

What could be the proper reason behind it? What is the solution?

What I need is to have a sidebar that shows up to `Tesla` allowing scrolling along Y-axis when the height of the `div` is more than the viewport.

You can find my whole code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rkabirr/0q4xnLby/3/):

Comment: If you remove this: `.sidenav { padding-top: 60px; }`, does the sidebar behave as expected?

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is the `padding-top` style applied directly to `.sidenav`. This element has `height: 100%;` but padding shifts it down (and `overflow-y` can't help).

In my opinion, best solution is to wrap all your nav links inside another div (in this example `.sideInner`) and then apply the padding style to that.

```js
document.getElementById('showlamborghini').onclick = start;

function start() {
  var z = document.getElementById('showid').style;
  z.display = (z.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideInner {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sideInner {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }

  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <div class="sideInner"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Google</a>
    <a href="#">Hyundai</a>
    <a href="#">Toyota</a>
    <a href="#">Mitsubishi</a>
    <a href="#">Corolla</a>
    <a href="#">Audi</a>
    <a href="#">McLaren</a>
    <a href="#">Grace</a>
    <a href="#">Raus</a>
    <a href="#">Electra</a>
    <a href='#' id='showlamborghini'>Lamborghini</a>

    <div id='showid' style='display:none'>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Company Owners</a>
      <a href="#">Shares</a>
      <a href="#">Market Value</a>
      <a href="#">Economical Issues</a>
      <a href="#">Adress</a></div>
    <a href="#">Tesla</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```